# Differences in string values when stored as .env variable vs system variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am playing around with a node.js application for the first time, noodling about with a simple hello world app, and have run into an odd problem that does not make sense to me.

I have a `.env` file that has a string containing a 'newline' character as one of it's values:

```
  foo="up\ndown"
```

I also have a system environment variable (I am using Windows 10) that has the same value:

[image]

I then run the following code:

```
  const foo = process.env.foo;
  const bar = process.env.bar;

  console.log(foo);
  console.log(bar);

  const fooObj = {
    foo: process.env.foo
  };

  const barObj = {
    bar: process.env.bar
  };

  console.log(fooObj);
  console.log(barObj);
```

The result of which (in a terminal view within Visual Studio Code) is this:

```
up
down
up\ndown
{ foo: 'up\ndown' }
{ bar: 'up\\ndown' }
```

I do not understand why the two strings are being treated differently, i.e. why `foo` has `\n` in it when inserted into the object, but `bar` has `\\n` in the same scenario.

Why is the 'newline' character being interpreted differently between the two instances?

Answer (score 0):

How is .env file after you add "foo" and "bar" env variable to it?

When I added as you described, I am getting the expected console output. PFB,

```
up
down
up
down
{ foo: 'up\ndown' }
{ bar: 'up\ndown' }
```

Probably, if you add up in the first line and add down in the second line in the image shown above. It should work as expected.